# Github actions: Stop Github showing all workflow files under "Actions-> All Workflows"

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have a bog standard workflow pipeline, of which there are 2 main workflow scripts:

`workflow_build-deploy-service.yaml`:

```
name: Build and Deploy Service
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:

  build:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-check-quality.yaml
    secrets: inherit

      deploy-docker-image:
        needs: build
        runs-on:
          - self-hosted
          - build
        permissions:
          id-token: write
          contents: read
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
            ...
```

and `workflow_build-pull-request.yaml`:

```
name: Build PR
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]
jobs:
  build:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-check-quality.yaml
    secrets: inherit
```

Then, there is a whole bunch of "include" scripts that are used from these 2 scripts:

```
build-and-check-quality.yaml
deploy-to-env.yaml
run-e2e-tests.yaml
```

Here's the code sample for `deploy-to-env.yaml`

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: The name of the environment to deploy to
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on:
      - self-hosted
      - build
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
```

None of the include scripts have a name, and the idea had been that in Github-> Actions I only see the above 2 main scripts so that our team members could easily identify and run a build job to a required level (`Build PR` or full `Build and Deploy Service`).

Instead, I can see all the include files listed there as if they were runnable workflows:

[image]

How can I hide the files from being listed in Github actions as if they were runnable jobs?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to move those extra include scripts into a separate repository, convert them into resuable actions, and share them with the main repository. Then refrence the scripts in the separate repository from your "Build and Deploy" and "Build PR" actions.

Relevant GitHub docs are:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-from-your-private-repository